# cd to user defined path in python

Tags: command-line, python

I was wondering if you could help me with my new python program. I recently added a browse button to the GUI to make things more "user-friendly." I told python to only accept *.pvt files when the user is asked to browse for a file... Now, I am left wondering how to tell python to take the path the user browsed to and open a cmd window[using subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe")] and cd to that user defined path.. any ideas???

Comment: This question belongs on Stack Overflow, since it is specifically about programming.

Comment: @jathanism Don't be a snob, particularly with new users.

Comment: please click the checkmark next to the most helpful answer to your questions, its a small way to thank those that help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen()` accepts a `cwd` argument:

```
Popen(["cmd.exe"], cwd=mypath)
```

Comment: hmm, still doesn't work... would there be a different way of opening a cmd window and cd'ing to that given directory?

Comment: @user: If an answer doesn't work, do not mark it as accepted; instead explain what *exactly* doesn't work. No `cmd.exe` window? Wrong startup directory? Computer on fire?